# Value of bias in floating point representation

Tags: java

While reading single precision floating point number, I came to know that bias 127 is added to convert signed exponent into unsigned exponent. But the lowest number possible for signed exponent which is in 2's complement representation is `-2^(8-1) = -128`. Then,  why bias is 127, why not 128?

Comment: Math expressions are often easier to understand in "verbatim" mode.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from [IEEE standard representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

I think in your calculations you're not taking into account the fact that floats have special values to represent `+Inf`, `-Inf`, `NaN`. So it's like `-126..127`, not `-128..127`.

Comment: yes, you r right that it comes from IEEE representation but I want to get clarified if the purpose of bias is to eliminate negatives.As far as +Inf,-Inf, NaN

Comment: .As far as +Inf,-Inf, NaN is concerned these comes when biased exponent is 255(exponent =128),this fact I am also taking into account.